# Sending packets on a dead port then stopping when accepting

Tags: ssh, iptables

I have programmed iptables to protect my Ubuntu installation. I have SSH but I have put it on another port than 22 for brute-force attacks.
However this morning, a single ip tried to connect every 30s-1m on the 22 port (which is dropped by iptable) leading to more than 1k packets.
As I was wondering what it was doing, I temporarily opened forward this port on SSH. Then I saw he tried to connect as root, was found by fail2ban (but not banned) and then it was disconnected.
And from this moment, attemps just stopped from this ip.

So I have some questions :

- How did he know they was a server here when drop is normally hiding? It was random?
- Why did he try so hard on a dead port and then suddently stopped when request was created. He only tried once.
- What are the CPU/performance required to drop the packets? Could I be DDos by one or more IPs flooding dead port?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: How did he know they was a server here when drop is normally hiding? It was random?

If your system responds to other inquiries, ping for example and the most common, then the bad guy might know that way. Otherwise yes, often it is just random.

Question 2: Why did he try so hard on a dead port and then suddently stopped when request was created? He only tried once.

You will go crazy trying to understand the logic of these bad guys. Very often it doesn't make any sense at all. It is likely a poorly programmed bot.

Question 3: What are the CPU/performance required to drop the packets? Could I be DDos by one or more IPs flooding dead port?

Very little to negligible resources involved for your low packets per unit time example. No, these type of rates would not constitute a DOS (Denial Of Service) or DDOS (Distributed Denial Of Service) attack. If the port were flooded at a very high packets per unit time rate it could start to saturate your network connection from your ISP, becoming a (D)DOS.

Comment: Okay so if it is one of the best option regarding CPU, that’s great. So I can keep the firewall to drop all this stuff and limit CPU saturation and maybe even ddos. However it is currently poor attacks on old exploits or random ssh try but this time I could not find any logic but I will stop trying to.